# Exhausting Memory - Tried Fixing Loops, Still Does Not Work

Tags: php, mysql, memory, memory-management

I'm currently experiencing a memory usage issue - but I cannot figure out where. I've tried replacing some of my foreach loops with for loops or by issuing another query to the DB, but I am still gettting the same error - "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in  on line 109". Can anyone provide some insight as to what may be causing the issue? Thank you!

Code after @Patrick 's answer:

```
    $participating_swimmers = array();  
    $event_standings = array();
    $qualifying_times = array();

    $events = array();

        $current_event = '';
        $select_times_sql = "SELECT event, time, name, year, team, time_standard, date_swum
                            FROM demo_times_table
                            WHERE sex = 'M' AND (time_standard = 'A' OR time_standard = 'B')
                            ORDER BY event, time ASC";
        $select_times_query = mysql_query($select_times_sql);
        //Create array with the current line's swimmer's info
        while ($swimmer_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_times_query)) {
            if($current_event != $swimmer_info['event']){
                $events[] = $current_event = $swimmer_info['event'];
            }

            //Create array with the current line's swimmer's info
            $swimmer_info["time"] = $select_times_row['time'];
            $swimmer_info["name"] = $select_times_row['name'];
            $swimmer_info["year"] = $select_times_row['year'];
            $swimmer_info["team"] = $select_times_row['team'];
            $swimmer_info["time_standard"] = $select_times_row['time_standard'];
            $swimmer_info["date_swum"] = $select_times_row['date_swum'];

            //Create "Top 8" list - if more than 8 A cuts, take them all
            if (($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "A") || ($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "B")) {               
                //Check if there are 8 or less entries in the current event, or if the swim is an A cut
                if ((count($event_standings[$current_event]) < 8) || ($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "A")) {
                    //Add swimmer to the list of invites
                    $event_standings[$current_event][] = $swimmer_info;

                    //Keep only the identifying information about the swimmer
                    $condensed_swimmer_info["name"] = $swimmer_info["name"];
                    $condensed_swimmer_info["year"] = $swimmer_info["year"];
                    $condensed_swimmer_info["team"] = $swimmer_info["team"];

                    //Check if swimmers name already appears in list
                    if (!in_array($condensed_swimmer_info, $participating_swimmers)) {
                        //It is a unique user - add them to the list
                        $participating_swimmers[] = $condensed_swimmer_info;
                    }
                } else {
                    //Add the qualifying time that did not fit into the list to a list of qualifying times
                    $qualifying_times[$current_event][] = $swimmer_info;    
                }
            }
        }

    //Sort each array of times in descending order

    arsort($event_standings);
    arsort($qualifying_times);
    $num_of_swimmers = count($participating_swimmers);

    while ($num_of_swimmers < 80) {
foreach ($events as $loe) {
    $num_of_qualifying_times = count($qualifying_times[$loe]);
    $swimmer_info = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1];
    $event_standings[$loe][] = $swimmer_info;

     //Keep only the identifying information about the swimmer
    $condensed_swimmer_info["name"] = $swimmer_info["name"];
    $condensed_swimmer_info["year"] = $swimmer_info["year"];
    $condensed_swimmer_info["team"] = $swimmer_info["team"];            
    //Check if swimmers name already appears in list
    if (!in_array($condensed_swimmer_info, $participating_swimmers)) {
        //It is a unique user - add them to the list
        $participating_swimmers[] = $condensed_swimmer_info;
    }

    //Remove time from array of qualifying times
    unset($qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1]);
}
$new_num_of_swimmers = count($participating_swimmers);
if($num_of_swimmers == $new_num_of_swimmers) break;
else $num_of_swimmers = $new_num_of_swimmers;
    }


    arsort($event_standings);
    arsort($qualifying_times);
    foreach($event_standings as $loe => $event_swimmer) {
    echo "<h1>",$loe,"</h1><br />"; 
    foreach ($event_swimmer as $es) {
        echo $es["time"],"  ",$es["name"],"  ",$es["team"],"<br />";
    }
    }
```

Comment: There are only 606 items in the database, so the amount of items is small.

Comment: Have you tried the quick and dirty `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`?

Comment: +1 for the dirty method , but if his database is large , he needs more of RAM .

Comment: @Jim , you are doing a while loop inside a while loop try `mysql_free_result` at end of each loop .

Comment: Just tried that, now I get a "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <my directory>  on line 117" error. So I'm doing something wrong in that loop!

Comment: Alex and Ronan, tried both of those together, and still getting the 30 secs max execution time. I added the myql_free_result($query) to the end of the "while ($num_of_swimmers < 80)" loop, as well as " mysql_free_result($query);
 mysql_free_result($select_times_query);" after the first two while loops end.

Comment: set event,sex to "varchar" type , and index it , and index time also if it is INT

Comment: btw there's no need for the first query and the first while loop !!! i just noticed they are in the same table , updated my answer

Comment: @Jim: are you sure that the while condition `$num_of_swimmers < 80` could become `false` ? Just do an `echo $num_of_swimmers` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @M42 I've checked that, I played with lower numbers and same result. THank you though!

Comment: My suggestion is look at the while loop. Make sure it's not getting bogged down in there. Unfortunately, you haven't told us which line 109 is, so it's difficult to assess the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Large data in database is the problem 95% !
- try using `limit x,y` in your queries , and put those queries in some loop .
- see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php it might help

```
<?php

    $participating_swimmers = array();  
    $event_standings = array();
    $qualifying_times = array();

    $select_times_sql = "SELECT *
                        FROM demo_times_table
                        WHERE sex = 'M'
                        ORDER BY time ASC";
    $select_times_query = mysql_query($select_times_sql);
    while ($select_times_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_times_query)) {
        //Create array with the current line's swimmer's info
        $swimmer_info["time"] = $select_times_row['time'];
        $swimmer_info["name"] = $select_times_row['name'];
        $swimmer_info["year"] = $select_times_row['year'];
        $swimmer_info["team"] = $select_times_row['team'];
        $swimmer_info["time_standard"] = $select_times_row['time_standard'];
        $swimmer_info["date_swum"] = $select_times_row['date_swum'];

        //Create "Top 8" list - if more than 8 A cuts, take them all
        if (($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "A") || ($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "B")) {               
            //Check if there are 8 or less entries in the current event, or if the swim is an A cut
            if ((count($event_standings[$current_event]) < 8) || ($swimmer_info["time_standard"] == "A")) {
                //Add swimmer to the list of invites
                $event_standings[$current_event][] = $swimmer_info;

                //Keep only the identifying information about the swimmer
                $condensed_swimmer_info["name"] = $swimmer_info["name"];
                $condensed_swimmer_info["year"] = $swimmer_info["year"];
                $condensed_swimmer_info["team"] = $swimmer_info["team"];

                //Check if swimmers name already appears in list
                if (!in_array($condensed_swimmer_info, $participating_swimmers)) {
                    //It is a unique user - add them to the list
                    $participating_swimmers[] = $condensed_swimmer_info;
                }
            } else {
                //Add the qualifying time that did not fit into the list to a list of qualifying times
                $qualifying_times[$current_event][] = $swimmer_info;    
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result($select_times_query);
    //Sort each array of times in descending order

    arsort($event_standings);
    arsort($qualifying_times);
    $num_of_swimmers = count($participating_swimmers);


        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(event)
                FROM demo_times_table
                WHERE sex = 'M' limit 80";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $loe = $row['event'];
            $num_of_qualifying_times = count($qualifying_times[$loe]);
            $event_standings[$loe][] = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1];

             //Keep only the identifying information about the swimmer
            $condensed_swimmer_info["name"] = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times]["name"];
            $condensed_swimmer_info["year"] = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times]["year"];
            $condensed_swimmer_info["team"] = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times]["team"];            
            //Check if swimmers name already appears in list
            if (!in_array($condensed_swimmer_info, $participating_swimmers)) {
                //It is a unique user - add them to the list
                $participating_swimmers[] = $condensed_swimmer_info;
            }

            //Remove time from array of qualifying times
            unset($qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1]);
        }
        $num_of_swimmers = count($participating_swimmers);
        mysql_free_result($query);


    arsort($event_standings);
    arsort($qualifying_times);
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(event)
                FROM demo_times_table
                WHERE sex = 'M'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $loe = $row['event'];
            echo "<h1>".$loe."</h1><br />"; 

            foreach ($event_standings[$loe] as $es) {
                echo $es["time"]."  ".$es["name"]."  ".$es["team"]."<br />";
            }
    }

    /*
    foreach ($participating_swimmers as $ps) {
        echo $ps["name"]."<br /><br />";    
    }
    echo "<br /><br />";
*/
?>
```

Comment: I only have 606 items in the table - I wouldn't say that is large, would you?

Comment: Nope, back to the beginning error, it throws the memory issue when its running through the 2nd round of loops, the "while ($num_of_swimmers < 80) {" loop.

Comment: it would be better if you "always" index columns that are used in searching stuff in database (those used after `where`) , this will make your database faster . one time , a query took me about 16 minutes execution , when i indexed some stuff it dropped to 3 seconds ...

Comment: could you paste the whole file here or somewhere else ?

Comment: PHP code: http://www.2shared.com/file/uOEZGv7x/times.html   table creation code: http://www.2shared.com/document/1U6rH8ci/demo_times_table.html

Comment: That first query can't work that way - I need the run the while() loop, inserting the times, but for the current event. I need a query to select the current event

Comment: in your previous while loop , the event are all events where sex=male , this means you can just ignore the event selection , unless you have events unrelated to sex=male

Comment: $select_times_sql = "SELECT *
                        FROM demo_times_table
                        WHERE sex = 'M' and even='some_event' 
                        ORDER BY time ASC";

Comment: @Ronan that last SQL statement you posted is what I need, but I need "some event" to be looped through - thats why I have the first loop. I need to to select the list of events from the database, and then run the qualifying times for each event

Comment: ` $select_times_sql = "SELECT *
                        FROM demo_times_table
                        WHERE sex = 'M' and event in (select distinct(event) from demo_times_table where sex='M')
                        ORDER BY time ASC"; `   but believe me this is useless , it just spends time . also open phpmyadmin and convert ehe `sex` and `even` columns to be varchar and the most important INDEX them .

Comment: I've converted the sex and event columns to index, but I am still experiencing the problem. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Similar to the first error - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)

Comment: are you sure theres no other applications eating up the memory ? heavy applications maybe like photoshop ? try restarting your PC , stopping some softwares . i have imported the database and it worked like a charm along with the code !!!

Comment: and try to replace mysql_fetch_assoc with mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a query within a query, with the potential for logic holes that create a never-ending loop, you can condense it into a single query. For your first block, both loops are just checking for the current event and the sex of the participant, right? So:

```
$result = SELECT * FROM <my database> WHERE sex = 'M' ORDER BY time ASC
```

Then you can pull whichever rows you want during the while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) loop and compensate for non-distinct values in another way.

One other source of the never-ending loop could be in the block where you sort the qualifying times. You're using "unset" after each, which could be getting the pointer stuck. You could try adding array_values($qualifying_times) after the unset to reindex the array.

Comment: TKM, your solution is similar to Ronan's - and so far it hasn't solved it yet. I tried adding the array_values, and that still does not solve the problem (I remove the last item from the array anyway, so I don't see why it would have to re-organize itself. But I put the code there anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Frist off, lose the SELECT DISTINCT like so:

```
$events = array()

$current_event = '';
$select_times_sql = "SELECT event, time, name, year, team, time_standard, date_swum
                    FROM demo_times_table
                    WHERE sex = 'M' AND (time_standard = 'A' OR time_standard = 'B')
                    ORDER BY event, time ASC";
$select_times_query = mysql_query($select_times_sql);
//Create array with the current line's swimmer's info
while ($swimmer_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_times_query)) {
    if($current_event != swimmer_info['event']){
        $events[] = $current_event = $swimmer_info['event'];
    }
//Create "Top 8" list - if more than 8 A cuts, take them all
//Check if there are 8 or less entries in the current event, or if the swim is an A cut
```

This also loses a bit of redundant code, and can speed up the final output (note the commas in the echo statements - the string doesn't need to be concatenated before it is spat out)

```
foreach($event_standings as $loe => $event_swimmer) {
    echo "<h1>",$loe,"</h1><br />"; 
    foreach ($event_swimmer as $es) {
        echo $es["time"],"  ",$es["name"],"  ",$es["team"],"<br />";
    }
}
```

The final problem lies in the second while loop, where the info being put into $condensed_swimmer_info doesn't have the -1 in place, thus is always blank, and $num_of_swimmers never rises to more than 1 over its original value:

```
while ($num_of_swimmers < 80) {
    foreach ($events as $loe) {
        $loe = $row['event'];
        $num_of_qualifying_times = count($qualifying_times[$loe]);
        $swimmer_info = $qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1];
        $event_standings[$loe][] = $swimmer_info;

         //Keep only the identifying information about the swimmer
        $condensed_swimmer_info["name"] = $swimmer_info["name"];
        $condensed_swimmer_info["year"] = $swimmer_info["year"];
        $condensed_swimmer_info["team"] = $swimmer_info["team"];            
        //Check if swimmers name already appears in list
        if (!in_array($condensed_swimmer_info, $participating_swimmers)) {
            //It is a unique user - add them to the list
            $participating_swimmers[] = $condensed_swimmer_info;
        }

        //Remove time from array of qualifying times
        unset($qualifying_times[$loe][$num_of_qualifying_times-1]);
    }
    $new_num_of_swimmers = count($participating_swimmers);
    if($num_of_swimmers == $new_num_of_swimmers) break;
    else $num_of_swimmers = $new_num_of_swimmers;
}
```

Comment: I don't have anything on my current system to test this, but it should be a simple matter to work out any remaining issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response Patrick! I put the code as an edit to my first post. it outputs the event names, but no times for the events. I've gotta run to work, but I will check through later to see where the information is being lost.